# Definability of Models in propositional calculus

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I have the following question:
If I have two models which are defined as followed -
$$ v_1(p_i)=T \leftrightarrow 2|i $$
$$ v_2(p_i)=T \leftrightarrow \exists k \in \mathbb{N}. i=2k+1 $$

Is there a Set X such that $Ass(X)= \{ v_1, v_2 \}$

If not - how can I show that?

I would also like to generalize that question - is a set with any two models definable?

Thanks!

Comment: What is $\mathrm{Ass}$?

Comment: In propositional claculus, a "model" of a formula $\varphi$ is an assignment $v$ such that $v$ satisfies $\varphi$ : $v \vDash \varphi$.

Comment: $Ass(X)= \{ v | v \models X \} $

Comment: $ v \models X \leftrightarrow \forall \phi \in X. v \models \phi $

Comment: $v_1$ satisfies every prop letter with index even and $v_2$ satisfies every prop letetr with index odd, but e.g. $v_1,v_2 \vDash p_1 \lor p_2$. Thus, in general, every disjunction with at least one odd and one even id satisfied by both.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Yes you are correct. But then also other models will be satisfied by this criteria, so this will not show the definability of this set of two models.

Answer (score 1):

**CPL** = *classical propositional calculus*

Let $\mathcal{L}$ be a set of all formulas of **CPL**. By a complete set $T$ of formulas of **CPL** I mean a subset of $\mathcal{L}$ such that there exists a model $\nu$ such that
$$T = \big\{\phi\,\big|\,\nu\Vdash \phi\big\}$$
Note that such $T$ has the following properties:

**1.** For every formula $\phi$ either $\phi\in T$ or $\neg \phi \in T$
**2.** If $\phi\in T$, then for every formula $\psi$ we have $\phi\vee\psi \in T$.
**3.** If $\phi_1,...,\phi_n\in T$, then $\phi_1\wedge ...\wedge \phi_n\in T$.

We will use these properties below.

**Fact.** *Let $T, T_1,...,T_n$ be complete sets of formulas for **CPL**. If
$$T_1\cap T_2\cap ...\cap T_n\subseteq T$$
then there exists $k$ such that $T=T_k$.*

**Proof.** We show first that $T_k\subseteq T$ for some $k$. Suppose to the contrary that for each $1\leq k\leq n$ there exists $\phi_k\in T_k$ such that $\phi_k\in T_k\setminus T$. Then $\neg \phi_k\in T$ according to **1**. Thus also $(\neg \phi_1)\wedge (\neg \phi_2)\wedge...\wedge (\neg \phi_k)\in T$ according to **3**. Hence 
$$\phi_1\vee \phi \vee...\vee \phi_k\not \in T$$ 
On the other hand since $\phi_k\in T_k$, we derive that $\phi_1\vee\phi_2\vee ...\vee\phi_n\in T_k$ by **2**. Thus
$$\phi_1\vee\phi_2\vee ...\vee\phi_n\in T_1\cap T_2\cap ...\cap T_n \subseteq T$$
This is a contradiction and hence we proved that $T_k\subseteq T$ for some $1\leq k\leq n$. This implies that $T_k = T$, because by definition complete sets of formulas are maximal among consistent sets of formulas.

Now consider $T_1, T_2$ complete sets of formulas corresponding to $\nu_1,\nu_2$, respectively. Let $X= T_1\cap T_2$. Clearly $\nu_1\Vdash X$ and $\nu_2\Vdash X$. On the other hand suppose that $\nu\Vdash X$. Let $T$ be a complete set corresponding to $\nu$. Then $X = T_1\cap T_2\subseteq T$. By **Fact** we have $T_1 = T$ or $T_2 = T$. This means that $\nu = \nu_1$ or $\nu = \nu_2$. Hence $\mathrm{Ass}(X) = \{\nu_1,\nu_2\}$.

**The general case.**
Consider the set of all models $M$ of **CPL**. We define a topology $\tau$ on $M$. Basis of $\tau$ consists of sets
$$M(\phi) = \{\nu \in M\,|\,\nu \Vdash \phi\}$$
One can easily verify that this is a topology on $M$. This topology (as it is intuitively clear from its definition) is closely related to metalogical properties of **CPL**. Closed subsets in the topology are of the form
$$V(X) = \{\nu \in M\,|\,\forall_{\phi \in X} \nu \not \Vdash \phi\} $$
From this description you can prove that the compactness theorem for $\Vdash$ is equivalent to the compactness of $(M,\tau)$.

It also turns out that closed subsets of $\tau$ are precisely definable sets. The **Fact** above really says that finite sets of models are closed in $\tau$.

Comment: This is beautiful. Thank you. So we have that for any finite number of models there is a set that defines it. What is the problem in claiming this to an infinite number of models?

Comment: @Cantor I will edit my answer and add infinite case.

Comment: But then we have a problem. For it means that any set of models is definable. But we know there are sets that are undefinable, like the set of all the models that give the value of T to only a finite number of atomic formulas.

Comment: I am not claiming that all infinite sets are definable, but I will add certain result describing which of them are definable. Be patient :).